# Extract particular string and value using bash shell script

Tags: bash

I have just started with BASH shell scripting journey so need help with few commands.

I need to extract particular string from "ps -ef | grep <processName>

This gives output like below:

```
weblogic   31761 30873  5 02:44 ?        00:10:51 /m1/appl/jdk/bin/java -d64 -Xms1024m -Xmx2700m -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/m1/appl/instance/debug -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=settings=default -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=200 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:+PrintConcurrentLocks -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:CompileThreshold=1000 -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:NewRatio=7 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=3072m -cp /m1/appl/fmw/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic-launcher.jar -Dlaunch.use.env.classpath=true -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/m1/appl/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dhttps.proxyHost=XX.XX.XX.XX -Dweblogic.heapDumpPathOnDeadlock=/m1/appl/instance/debug -Dhttps.proxySet=true
```

how can I extract value of "-Dhttps.proxyHost"?

XX.XX.XX.XX

can awk and substr be useful here?

Comment: Please specify the actual shell. A programming language called "shell script" doesn't exist! As a new user heer, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Apologies.. it's bash shell

Comment: [edit] your question, please! Check both the text and the tags that you applied.

Answer (score 0):

Either one of these commands:

```
... | grep -Po '(?<=-Dhttps.proxyHost=)[^[:space:]]+'
... | awk -v RS=' ' -F = '$1 == "-Dhttps.proxyHost" { print $2 }'
```